# resize! for 2-dimensional arrays (matrices) in Julia

Tags: memory-management, julia

The function `resize!()` in `Base` takes care of carefully allocating memory to accommodate a given vector size of given type:

```
v = Vector{Float64}(3)
resize!(v, 5) # allocates two extra indices
```

Since Julia is column-major, I was wondering if it would be possible to define a `resizecols!` function for matrices that would allocate extra columns in an efficient way:

```
A = Matrix{Float64}(3,3)
resizecols!(A, 5) # allocates two extra columns
```

This is useful in many statistical methods where the number of training examples is not known a priori in a loop. One can start allocating a design matrix `X` with `n` columns and then expand it if necessary in the loop.

Comment: You cannot resize matrices right now. I think there's an open issue for this.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisRackauckas, I tried searching for the issue on GitHub, but couldn't find it. Please let me know if you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [ElasticArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/ElasticArrays.jl) defines an array type that can be resized in the last dimension. Perfect for the case of resizing the columns of a matrix efficiently.